# How to scale out image hosting/serving?

Tags: architecture, web, scalability, media, cluster-computing

I'm building a website where users can upload photos and I'd also convert uploaded photos into thumbnails.

Planning ahead, if the website gets popular, how do I scale it out so that the images (both original and thumbnails) will be stored in and served from multiple servers? Maybe a cluster? Is there any open source software that would help me in this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a very interesting question that I would like to know the answer to. Upvoted! :)

Comment: Interesting indeed, but perhaps a better place for it is on http://serverfault.com ?

Comment: Voted to move to Serverfault. I guess you may get better answers there

Comment: I think this question accepts answers of two kinds: development-based and infrastructure-based. If we want to give it a chance to get development-based answers, it should not be moved to serverfault. I suggest that @Continuation posts the same question there with a link here in order to get infrastructure-based answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting question.

I think that the most solid and easily scaled solution would be to use something like [MogileFS](http://www.danga.com/mogilefs/) which is a distributed HTTP based file-system.

Another approach which might be simpler to build is to just make sure you're aware of how you would scale out your image hosting should you need to. Possible approaches could be:
 - Use Amazon S3
 - Implement the sharding/partitioning of images manually in your application, store the images on different backend servers (with slower/large storage) and then put a reverse proxy in front of it.

In my opinion MogileFS would be a great solution to this problem. To scale out should be trivial but the initial implementation might take a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

Buy it don't build it. Akamai and Amazon CloudFront and their ilk commoditize this. Don't reinvent the wheel, it's really a specialist function that is easily and reliably outsourced much more cheaply than it is built in-house.

Answer (score -2):

Well one way of approaching this is to convert the image file into binary format and save the binary into a database.

I have used php to convert the images into blob format and store these blobs on a mysql database.  When the files are in the database you can use php scripts to convert the blob back into the mime type like jpeg or gif and display then on the webpage.

So your files are then centrally stored on a database, you can place the scripts which convert the blobs into images on any number of servers.

I have never found any open source software to use this method of storage but it is fairly straight forward to create the scripts.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't think this is a good solution at all. What happens when the size of your images is larger than a single db instance. It is very rare that storing images as blobs in a database is a good solution.

Comment: It's also generally slower than filesystem operations, and that particular solution doesn't look like it would scale, since all of your images are really just coming from one machine anyway.